# Update data using add action

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

I'm use Grocery CRUD. I create custom button using add_action.

The button for change data to 0. So, after click the button database update column to 0.

Controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Attendance extends Admin_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_builder');
    }

public function attendance($visitor_id)
    {
        $attendance_status = array(
            'attendance_status' => 0
        );

        $update = $this->Attendace_model->update_attendance_status($visitor_id,$attendance_status);

       if($update)
       {
           $this->load->view('Attendance');
       }
       else
       {
           alert("error");
       }
   }
}
```

Model :

```
<?php

class Attendance_model extends MY_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function update_attendance_status($visitor_id,$attendance_status)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $visitor_id);
        $this->db->update('invitation_codes', $attendance_status);
    }
}
```

What code to use in function for update the data to 0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller:

```
   public function attendance($visitor_id)
   {
           $attendance_status = array(
           'attendance_status' => 0
           );

       $update = $this->YOUR_MODEL_NAME- >update_attendance_status($visitor_id,$attendance_status);

       if($update)
      {
         return true;
      }
      else
      {
         return false;
      }
   }
```

Model :

```
  public function update_attendance_status($visitor_id,$attendance_status)
 {
  $this->db->where('id', $visitor_id);
  $this->db->update('invitation_codes', $attendance_status);
 }
```

Comment: Oh, must create model for function? I think model not important.

Comment: Your code is also right i try and it's Work
Can you please send error

Comment: return true replace $this->load->view('Your_view_file');

and also check your database value change or not  ???

Comment: Not return true or false. I don't know why. Error 404 The page you requested was not found. Or my code have wrong.

Comment: create .htaccess file and htaccess code to this url

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

check its work

Comment: Bro, have two error when I click. First `Message: Undefined property: CI::$Attendace_model` adn second `Message: Call to a member function update_attendance_status() on null`

Comment: pleasw send me all view and controller code 

start from end

Comment: Just add `$this->load->model('Attendance_model');` . Code work !